# Regex to extract key value by brackets

Tags: python, regex

I want to get key and value from text in a `[key] value` format:

1. key is fixed by AA, BB, CC.
2. [key](there can be blank)value
3. value can have '[', ']' and new line(\n).
4. value can be null.
5. If there's [DD], it is value.

For example,

```
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC] (can null)
```

and my Python code is this:

```
import re

text ='''
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]
'''
pattern = re.compile(this is what I want)
result = {m.group('field'):m.group('value') for m in pattern.finditer(text)}
```

If value is only one line like this

```
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]
```

then I can use below regex, and you can see https://regex101.com/r/rS8oM1/1

```
\[(?P<key>AA|BB|CC)\]\s*(?P<value>.*)
```

Comment: `this is what I want` looks a poor effort. Did you try at least something?

Comment: I think you should just clarify the requirements. `[\s|\S]*` = `[\s\S]*` matches any characters up to the end of string. What is the *output* you expect?

Comment: Please update your post showing expected result from your sample input text.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rS8oM1/1 please reference this link. If value is fixed one line, I can split extactly key and value pairs.

Comment: @Saleem I updated my post.
@WiktorStribiżew I want to split key and value. value is important, there can be `[` or `new line(\n)`.

Comment: Ok, I see, you just need to get the *key* (a `[AA]` or `[BB]` or `[CC]` only at the beginning of a line)  and a *value* (all text after the three alternative keys and before the next key or end of string). Right? Try [`(?s)\[(?P<key>AA|BB|CC)\]\s*(?P<value>(?:(?!\[(?:AA|BB|CC)]).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/iA9hE4/1). Or even [`(?sm)^\[(?P<key>AA|BB|CC)\]\s*(?P<value>(?:(?!\n\[(?:AA|BB|CC)]).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/iA9hE4/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right. and your answer is what I am looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you just need to get the *key* (a `[AA]` or `[BB]` or `[CC]` only at the beginning of a line) and a *value* (all text after the three alternative keys and before the next key or end of string).

You may use a regex based on a **tempered greedy token** that acts as a synonym of a *negated character class* for *sequences of characters*:

```
(?sm)^\[(?P<key>AA|BB|CC)\]\s*(?P<value>(?:(?!\n\[(?:AA|BB|CC)]).)*)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA9hE4/2)

The `(?:(?!\n\[(?:AA|BB|CC)]).)*` tempered greedy token matches any text that is not `\n[AA]` or `\n[BB]` or `\n[CC]`.

The `(?sm)` are inline modifiers: `(?s)` enables the DOTALL mode (`.` starts matching a newline, too) and `(?m)` makes `^` match the start of a line, not just the start of a string.

See [sample Python demo](https://ideone.com/vDRPIq):

```
import re

text ='''
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]
'''
pattern = re.compile(r'(?sm)^\[(?P<key>AA|BB|CC)\]\s*(?P<value>(?:(?!\n\[(?:AA|BB|CC)]).)*)')
result = {m.group('key'):m.group('value') for m in pattern.finditer(text)}
print(result)
# => {'AA': 'abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"\nblah blah\n[abc-def] this is also value.', 'CC': '', 'BB': 'abcd defg'}
```

Comment: That is a moot question. I just want to help those who need help and want to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

Just club the lines before applying regex to make your life easier:

```
>>> text ='''
... [AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
... blah blah
... [BB]abcd defg
... [CC]
... '''
>>> print(text)

[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]

>>> newtext=''
>>> for line in text.split('\n'):
...     newtext=newtext+('\n' if re.match('^\[\w\w\]', line) else '')+line
... 
>>> print(newtext)

[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"blah blah
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]
>>> for i in newtext.split('\n'):
...    print(re.findall(r'^\[(\w\w)\](.*)$',i))
... 
[]
[('AA', ' abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"blah blah')]
[('BB', 'abcd defg')]
[('CC', '')]
>>>
```

Edit1: with custom input..

```
$ cat a.py 
import re
text ='''
[AA] abcd
[abcd]
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]
'''
newtext=''
for line in text.split('\n'):
    newtext=newtext+('\n' if re.match('^\[\w\w\]', line) else '')+line

for i in newtext.split('\n'):
    print(re.findall(r'^\[(\w\w)\](.*)$',i))
$ python a.py 
[]
[('AA', ' abcd[abcd]')]
[('BB', 'abcd defg')]
[('CC', '')]
$
```

Comment: I edited post. If using your answer, if [AA]'s value is `abcd\n[abcd]`, this case you can not make one line it.

Comment: @Horangs it works with that input as well, note the logic for combining lines, that uses regex as well